# Compile C code for JVM or embed C runtime inside JVM

Tags: java, c++, c

[H3 library](https://github.com/uber/h3) is based on C code

And I would need to use it on a *platform* that only allows Java runtime to run.

Is it possible to compile C code to Java (jar) runnable on the JVM? Or embed a C runtime in the JVM?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, C code can not be executed by the VM. While there are ways to compile C to Java ([1](https://www.mtsystems.com/), [2](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/)) this might not be the best solution for you.

The typical way to interact with native code would be over [JNI (Java Native Interface)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)

Fortunately, you do not need to do this yourself. H3 already offers ready-made Java bindings:

https://github.com/uber/h3-java

You can simply use the bindings as dependency in your POM and then use the Java classes to interact with H3.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). This allows you to create a binding between native code (written in, for example, C) and Java code.